# Why array_agg() is returning empty array in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, array-agg

I have an integer type column named as start. I want to make an array by the values of this column. It seemed to be very easy and I used array_agg(), but it is giving empty array as output. Following is my column data

```
start
 1
 2
 11
 5
 .
 .
 . (and so on)
```

And following is my query used to make the array:

```
select array_agg(start) as start_array from table1;
```

Why is it giving empty array?

Comment: Is that really your entire query? You don't have any `WHERE` or other clause in addition to this?

Comment: This should work.  Are you sure the table really has data in it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes the table has data

Comment: @LukasEder I don't have any WHERE clause

Comment: It should works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26e97/1/1
How did you check result?

Comment: I don't know why the above query is giving me empty array. But the following query is running fine. `SELECT array(SELECT start FROM table1) as start_array`. What is the difference between array and array_agg?

Comment: @LSG post your sample data.

Comment: Also post the `select version()` and `\df+ array_agg`

Answer (score 1):

## It's not

There is no way that this can return empty unless there are no rows. Perhaps a JOIN or a WHERE clause is wrong and you have 0-rows?

Also as a micro-optimization if your query is this simple,

```
select array_agg(start) as start_array from table1;
```

Then it's [probably better written with the `ARRAY()` constructor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159710/2639)...

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT start FROM table1) AS start_array;
```